# Generic classes in generic methods

Tags: java, generics

I'm using the Mockito mock framework to mock a generic class in Java. The usage of the framework seems to be pretty clear from the documentation, I didn't find an example for mocking generic classes. The mock framework contains the following method:

```
public static <T> T mock(Class<T> classToMock) {
    ...
}
```

I have a generic type `IState<StateId, Event>` and I want to instantiate it using the above method. I tried the following:

```
IState<StateId, Event> mockState = Mockito.mock(IState.class);
```

I get the following warning for this code:

```
Type safety: The expression of type IState needs unchecked conversion to conform to IState<StateId,Event>
```

I think I know what the problem is. The `mock` method returns a type of `IState`, but the variable I'm assigning to is a specialized type `IState<StateId, Event>`, so I somehow need to tell it that the class I am creating is specifically `IState<StateId, Event>`, but I don't know what the syntax for this is. I tried the following ones, but they all gave syntax errors.

```
IState<StateId, Event> mockState = Mockito.mock(IState<StateId, Event>.class);
IState<StateId, Event> mockState = Mockito.mock(IState.class<StateId, Event>);
```

Comment: As this is a test (I assume because of mockito) you can just ignore the warning, there's no `IState.<StateId, Event> class` for `.class`

Comment: @RC: I can do that, but I'm still curious how these things are handled in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics in java are implemented via type erasure. It means that parameterized classes are checked by the compiler, but at runtime all classes are "raw" (for retrocompatibility reasons). A consequence of this is that there is only one Class object representing `IState`, and not an infinite number of classes corresponding to all possible parameters.

To disable the warning, add `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` just before the line.

Comment: Right. But in this case, how do I get rid of the warning?

Comment: That works, except that it's called `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` and I have to put it before the method. Also, it's not very elegant.